# BxSlider: Save position of slider when page is refreshed/changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

This is a tricky one and I'm not sure on how to go about this.

I'm using [BxSlider](http://www.bxslider.com) for a website which will slide through images like a normal typical slider. The problem is that I need a way to save the last position of the slider the user was on so that when they refresh or navigate to a different page on the site, it does not reset back to the first slide.

Picture example of what I mean:

[image: Position of slider]
[image]

Picture (1) : The current position of the slider.

Picture (2): The position of the slider after refresh or page change.

I need the slider to continue from the last slide rather than resetting back to the first slide.

Here is an example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/202/) of the slider as well as the HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
```

Any idea's will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that `bxSlider` offer: `startSlide` and `onSlideAfter`

You can look at their documentation here: [Docs](http://bxslider.com/options)

Then what you need to do it every time the slide changes you can store the current index using `localStorage.setItem()` and when the page is loaded you can retrieve the current index using `localStorage.getItem()`.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var startIndex = localStorage.getItem("currentIndex");
    if(startIndex == null)
        startIndex = 0;

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    startSlide: startIndex,
        mode: 'horizontal',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        auto: true,
        autoStart: true,
        autoDirection: 'next',
        autoHover: true,
        pause: 3000,
        autoControls: false,
        pager: true,
        pagerType: 'full',
        controls: true,
        captions: true,
        speed: 500,
        onSlideAfter: function($slideElm, oldIndex, newIndex) {save($slideElm, oldIndex, newIndex)}
});

    function save($slideElm, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        console.log(oldIndex + " " + newIndex);

        localStorage.setItem("currentIndex", newIndex);
    }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/1264/

Comment: This is perfect thanks. I've been stuck for hours trying to think of a method. You've saved me a lot of stress, thank you.